# How can a Spring Application be made to be single threaded or made to have one instance?

Tags: java, spring, thread-safety

I have a Spring application that is controlled with an API that we need to be single threaded, but I can not figure out how to accomplish this. The application is a re-factoring of an app that is single threaded. They want the same basic design for the new version, while using our new programming methods (i.e. Java, Spring, etc.) and adding extra functionality.

There is an API resource to start the application:

```
@RequestMapping("/start")
public String startProcess(){...}
```

If this gets called twice then the application will start another thread. **We want to stop this from happening**. But, we still want the stop API resource to work:

```
@RequestMapping("/stop")
public String stopProcess(){...}
```

The app has a typical Spring structure:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication{...}

@RestController
public class MyController{   
    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;
    ...}

@Service
@Transactional
public class CarolService{
    @Autowired
    private MyDAO myDAO;
    ...}

@Repository
public class myDAO{...}
```

How do I make sure that there is only one instance of this application running at a time? Please Help! And, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have actually two different problems: making your API single-threaded and making sure that there is only one instance of this application running at a time.

The solution is conceptually the same: you have to synchronize on some mutex. But it's much easier to do in the first case than in the second.

To make your API single-threaded you'll need to synchronize on something. If you have just one controller, just make API methods `synchronized`. If you have more than one controller, you'll need to create some application scope bean, inject it in every controller and synchronize on it. In old times there was also something like `SingleThreadModel`, but I think it was deprecated. Haven't seen it around for a few years but I won't be surprized if Spring would have a way of setting it somehow.

Making sure that there is only one instance of this application running at a time is much harder. You basically want to prevent anybody to start several copies of the application in parallel. One of the way to achieve this is to have some central shared resource like a database. On start-up the application will try to "acquire" the mutex by creating a record in some table (which would allow at most one record). If the record was created successfully, the application starts normally, if not then fails. You'll need some mechanism to detect stale mutex record - probably as simple as saving the timestamp in the mutex record and constantly updating it via scheduled task (heartbeat).

We recently had a similar task in an application running many instances of many microservices. We needed exactly one microservice to regularly execute certain maintenance task. We solved it by synchronising over a central MongoDB database. Microservices try to acquire the mutex by creating a document in a database collection. By design, at most one document may exist in that collection and the microservice which created the document performs the regular task and removes the document at the end. The collection is configured with an automatic clean-up so if the microservice failed to remove the document for whatever reason, it will be removed automatically by the database.